# How to print duplicate records if greater than 12 Times?

Tags: awk

How to print duplicate records which is repeated more than 12 time using awk.

Input:

```
1|abc123
2|abc123
3|abc123
4|abc123
5|abc123
6|abc123
7|abc123 
8|abc123
9|abc123 
10|abc123
11|abc123
12|abc123
13|cde456
14|xyz321
15|jkl245
16|abc123
17|abc123
18|abc123
19|def567
20|abc123
```

Expected output:

```
1|abc123
2|abc123
3|abc123
4|abc123
5|abc123
6|abc123
7|abc123 
8|abc123
9|abc123 
10|abc123
11|abc123
12|abc123
15|abc123
16|abc123
17|abc123
18|abc123
20|abc123
```

I tried below command, but i am not getting exact output.

```
awk -F'|' 'NR==FNR{cnt[$2]++; next} cnt[$2]>12' input > output
```

Comment: needs to print repeated records more than 2

Comment: Then why do you have lines appearing only 2 times into the expected output?

Comment: Its header of input file. if this value present more than 2time that means 2+ (PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H) print that entire line example 8|O315L4UB1BGTW03QRQW8L6J3936 this record present only 1time so we dont need that record

Comment: This is really confusing. `81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW` is clearly present in the input three times, not one time. Is the whetiespace at the end of the line significant?

Comment: Needs to print (81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW) if like this data present in the column more than 2times

Comment: Ok, so why is, for example, `6W0Q3WKP3DZ` mentioned in the output? It only occurs two times, but not more than two times. You said something about a header, what is the header in the data that you show?

Comment: @Joe, I think most people would read "more than 2" (n > 2) as strictly meaning that, i.e. "at least 3" (n >= 3). Your output would make sense with "2 or more" (n >= 2).

Comment: Joe, again your input has `12` lines with `abc123` (one of them has a trailing whitespace) and you ask to print lines with count *greater than* `12`, that means `13`, `14` etc.

Comment: Yes needs to print records repeated like 13,14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command will be good if you double parse the file, like:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{c[$2]++;next} c[$2]>12' input input > output
```

At first pass you count occurences and at second pass you print only for `c>12`. It is also memory efficient. Also the line order of the original file is honoured. You can easily enforce any sorting if you like.

By the way, your current input example has no lines appearing more than 12 times. `abc123` is appearing exactly `12` times. Additionally there is a trailing whitespace into one of these occurences, `7|abc123` , which means a different second field.

Comment: changing to `-F'[| ]'` would make it less sensitive to the trailing spaces

Comment: If someone is using `|` as the separator, they could probably use also spaces into the fields. If there is a different input test or requirement, I will update.

Comment: After changing -F'[| ]' also output returns zero

Comment: Still requirement makes you confuse?

Comment: Joe, please update the question with a meaningful example. Your current example contains also lines appearing only 2 times. Also if you use two separators, `-F'[| ]`' the lines appearing 3 times are printed, because there are trailing whitespaces except into last line.

Comment: My requirement is very simple. for example in 2 second field if AAA repeats more than 2 times print only those records. If AAA print only one time then leave that records

Comment: @Joe But if it repeats _only two times_? Because now you are saying **more than two** again, which is different from **two or more** (the same as "more than once").  It's also still unclear whether whitespace (the spaces at the end of each line) are significant or not, because if they are significant, then no record occurs more than twice.

Comment: Actual thing is original file size is 10M. In that total 36 column present file separated with | delimeter. based on last column that means 36th field will be alpha numeric character. In that filed for example this value(PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H ) present  more than 12times print only those records. Here it will take more example so keep it in short i just mention more than 2. But the thing is if (PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H ) it present more than 12 times print entire line

Comment: @Joe Please update the question with a corrected expected output.

Comment: awk -F'[| ] 'FNR==NR{c[$2]++;next} c[$2]>12' input > output returns--0

Comment: @Joe you have to use `input input > output` to double parse the file. The input file must be provided twice.

Comment: Thank you so much all for your patience.  this command itself worked for me. i missed to add 2 times input so that only it returns zero. After adding two times input now i am getting output

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you actually mean "2 or more" and not "more than 2", since that is the output you show, you can get your desired output using GNU core tools and a bit of sed:

```
$ sed 's/  *$//' file | tr '|' ' ' | sort -t ' ' -k 2 | uniq -Df1 | tr ' ' '|'
3|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
6|6W0Q3WKP3DZ
10|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
7|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
9|81TE22WWDEDCVXBAQ6F20Z86GFW
2|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
5|BWDY6IGYBDTMAVQA
1|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
4|PTPX9L1Y31QEL55H
```

- `sed 's/  *$//' file`: remove the extra spaces you have at the end of most lines, then
- `tr '|' ' '`: replace the `|` with a space, then
- `sort -t ' ' -k 2`  : sort on the second, space-delimited field, then
- `uniq -Df1`: keep only duplicated lines (`-D`) and ignore the first field (`-f1`) when checking for dupes; then
- `tr ' ' '|'`: convert the spaces back to `|` again.

Comment: Above command not working. Command itself not running

Comment: or `sort ... -k2 -k1n` to sort the line numbers too

Comment: Could you please help on awk, because actual input file size is 10M

Comment: @Joe 10M is nothing, that is a very small file. If it isn't working, I suspect you are not using Linux, so you do not have GNU tools. Please edit your question and tell us what operating system you are using. As for an awk solution, thanasis [gave you](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706046) a good one above. If you want "2 or more" and not "more than 2", just change `c[$2]>2` to `c[$2]>1` in thanasis's code.

Comment: GNU tool we are not using